# Remove Categories from Simple Products

Tags: magento2, category, simple-product, remove

Can anyone tell me how can i fetch all the Simple SKU's and remove all the categories from those SKU via PHP script in magento 2.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, create a new PHP file in your Magento directory which is the same level as `app`, `lib`, `pub` ... with the following content:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5G');

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$collectionFactory = $objectManager->create(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory::class);
/** @var Collection $collection */
$collection = $collectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', ['eq' => Type::TYPE_SIMPLE])->load();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $product->setData('category_ids', null)->save();
}
```

For example, you set the file name `removeAllCategoriesFromSimpleProducts.php`, to execute the script, you should run the following command from the SSH terminal:

```
php removeAllCategoriesFromSimpleProducts.php
```

Comment: Hello, i am getting error when i run this file.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'tommy-hilfiger-sunglasses-th-1556-s-08a-ir-black-gray-1' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID' in /var/www/vhosts/stagingdiscountedsunglasses/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91
Stack trace:

Comment: That means your URL Rewrites data (for products) has problem(s). To fix this issue, from admin, go to Marketing > URL Rewrites, and filter by the Request Path with the key in the error, you will see some duplicate records and you should resolve it. Or if you see many products have URL Rewrites duplicates, you should use an extension to resolve the issue: https://github.com/elgentos/magento2-regenerate-catalog-urls

Comment: i am having issue with suppose this url key " bvlgari-eyeglasses-bv4165-504-dark-havana-women-1" but i see only one entry in url rewrites https://prnt.sc/TKUNFF1veAIL . So there is no duplicate entry here

Comment: There are some issues with your URL Rewrites, please use the extension I mentioned above to re-generate URL Rewrites then run my code. I've tested my code before sharing the code (with Magento default with sample data and the site is multiple stores), so it should work as expected.

Comment: Can we achieve this with the help of raw mysql and php for removing categories

Comment: I assume you mean un-assign categories from a product as your original request. So, yes, we can but it is more complex and require a lot of time to investigate the raw sql and it is less safe compared to using Magento way (model, collection).